# wkhtmltopdf does not render fonts or background colors correctly

Tags: python, html, fonts, wkhtmltopdf

I have a python script generating a couple of hundred HTML files as reports. I then use PDFKit to convert those HTML files to PDF.

The styling is done by a downloaded copy of Bootstrap 5 because of network issues preventing me using the Bootstrap CDN.

The problem I have is that the HTML and the rendered PDF are not exactly the same. The font family and the background color of a cell are not rendered. Everything else is fine.

According to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/reboot/#native-font-stack the native font on Windows is `Segoe UI`. This font is available and installed on my workstation.

In order to get the HTML and generated PDF to be exactly the same, I need to do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><HEAD><meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="file:///C:/temp/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">           
<style>
  
    .specialcolour { 
        background-color: #071731; 
        color: white;
        }

     * {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Arial', sans-serif;
        }
                
</style><title>....
```

But all I'm doing is re-iterating what should be the native font by Bootstrap. I've experimented with a bunch of different font families and the result is the same.

So long as I specify the font family, the HTML and the PDF will look the same.

Any ideas about what is going on here?

Comment: So I've eventually downloaded the bootstrap source and then just picked out the specific elements I need, and then have my own CSS. Seems to now work.